# Cannot import module in Django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My Django project directory looks like this :
[image]

I can import from the CPRS_admin app folder to my main folder and it works fine.But the moment I import the CPRS_admin app folder to the recommendation_model app folder it shows the error ModuleNotFound.

[image]

This is the image of the import of CPRS_admin into CPRS and it works.

[image]

But the moment when I import CPRS_admin into a file under the recommendation_model app it shows this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add CPRS_admin to CPRS/settings.py

> INSTALLED_APPS = ['CPRS_admin',...]

Comment: Yeap... well I have figured out the issue... the issue is in Django a script cannot be run in the normal way, it needs to be run under the server, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Have you added CPRS_admin to installed apps in settings.py?